# Bootstrap columns will not align correctly, instead one is under the other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope someone can assist me. I am probably making a silly mistake, but I am following along with the Udacity video and the code looks identical. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Udacity logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
                    <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the path to your `bootstrap.css` correct? Might seem silly, but it's a common mistake.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same. The file path is: C:\Users\Eden\Desktop\Udacity\Intro to HTML and CSS\Portfolio\css and then the bootstrap.css file.

Comment: The relative path you try to access should depend on the path of the currently opened html file. I assume that your html file is in `Intro to HTML`. If that is the case, you should change the css path to `CSS/Portfolio/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: I have fixed it now, the two answers below were correct. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your code is dependent upon browser window width - the code `col-md-6` will only produce two columns on browser window width of 992px or wider.

Try replacing the class `col-md-6` with `col-sm-6` for both divs that use that class, that should ensure that even at smaller sizes, the columns display side-by-side.

Alternatively, make your screen wider to see how the columns move based upon screen width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Udacity logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
                    <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, that was a stupid mistake. I opened the browser to full-screen and it changed. I guess I will change it to "col-sm-6". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remember that Bootstrap is a mobile-first framework; if you want something applied at all sizes, use `col-xs-*` (`sm` works too in most cases though)

Comment: As per answer above mine, bear in mind that Bootstrap intentionally alters layout based upon screen size - this is Responsive Design. See here for more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the correct answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38490294/3718753) it's good practice to include multiple classes to your columns so that they scale appropriately to different screen sizes.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Udacity logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I never realised that. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right column sizes. xs is for 768 under, sm is between 768 and 991, md and lg are 991 over.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Udacity logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
                    <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work fine with your code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKLbvQ

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="Udacity logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
                    <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, it was a matter of resizing my window :)